# Twig не рендерит шаблон

Tags: twig

Решил ознакомиться с шаблонизатором twig.

```
require_once 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates/');
$view = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => '/files/cache', 'debug' => true));
```

Ошибок нету. Рендерю шаблон.

```
$view->render('index.php', array('name' => 'twig'));
```

В шаблоне только `{{name}}`, но когда запускаю - пустой экран. Ctrl + U в браузере - пусто. В чём может быть проблема?

P.S. В случае с `$loader = new Twig_Loader_String()` строка рендериться и проблем нету.

Comment: попробуйте return $view->render(...)?

Comment: @MasterAlex return срабатывает, но эффекта 0.

Comment: @MasterAlex мне стоит быть повнимательней, читая документацию, я как-то пропустил echo, но спасибо, что натолкнули на мою ошибку.

Comment: @sargss, ну да это срабатывает только в классах, когда нужно что-то возвращать, в вашем случае сделайте как в документации: echo $view->render('index.html', array('name' => 'twig'))   //
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html

Comment: @MasterAlex да, так и сделал, спасибо